# Splitting CSS into two files not behaving like if one file

Tags: css, tags, divide

Little confused her, ok actually a lot confused.

I am trying to get my page to act like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx98qgv1/).  When I use the CSS all in one file I still get the second picture below which has the CSS subMenu behind the Google map instead of infant of it.  Now, when I split the two CSS Menus, one for all Div tags and one for the menu system, I get the first image problem.[image: first Image]

[image]

```
.nav-bar ul li:hover > .mega-menu{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;

}
```

Any clue on what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably a problem with the stacking order of the elements but you would need to include the code for the elements that are related to the map in order for someone to diagnose the problem accurately.

Comment: @Daniel all the code is attached to the JSFiddle

Comment: yes but in the JSFiddle the code works fine, you need to include the code that is causing you trouble so that someone can recreate the problem and then help solve it.

Comment: @Daniel Ok, maybe some miscommunications here.  If you take the html code on the JSFiddle and call it index.html and then take the code in the CSS and call it main.css thats all the code that I am using.  The split in the CSS code happens at .nav-bar and below which is called menu.css.  There is no other code I am using.  Hope this clarifies things

Comment: @Scubadivingfool - the only explanation here is that you are not including the "second" script with all the menu styles. This is the same effect as removing the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lx98qgv1/2/ . You should have **two** `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">` elements.

Comment: @Kobi opps, my mistake, I thought it was there in the link.  here is the link with the  linked CSS.  https://jsfiddle.net/Lx98qgv1/1/

Comment: @Daniel please find the updated FJFiddle link in the above comment